# php memory limit 2000M exhausted

Tags: php, cakephp

Am trying to upload **Do not call list** xml file to MySql DB. The file size is 256MB. It gets uploaded but when its starts processing am looping the phone numbers and concatenating 1000 phone numbers in a variable. When it reaches the limit of 1000, am creating a INSERT query and executing the query. BUt the problem is after inserting 3,50,000 records it say **"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in /var/domains/htdocs/aim/leads/dnc on line 1308)"**.

Below is the code snippet.

```
                    if(($fp = fopen($destination,"r"))) {

                        $buffer = fgets($fp);
                        $objXml = new XML($buffer);
                        $lists = Set::reverse($objXml);

                        $buffer = fgets($fp);
                        $objXml = new XML($buffer);
                        $acc = Set::reverse($objXml);

                        try {
                            while(!feof($fp)){
                                $counter = 0;
                                $phonesNo = "";

                                while(!feof($fp) && ($buffer = fgets($fp)) && $counter != 1000){

                                    $objXml = "";
                                    $arrXml = "";

                                    $objXml = new XML($buffer);

                                    $arrXml = Set::reverse($objXml);


                                    $counter++;
                                    if(isset($arrXml['Ph']['val']))
                                        $phonesNo .= "(".$acc['Ac']['val'].$arrXml['Ph']['val']."),";

                                }

                                $phonesNo = substr($phonesNo,0,-1);
                                $sql = "INSERT INTO do_not_call_lists (`phone`) VALUES " .$phonesNo;

                                unset($phonesNo);
                                $this->Lead->query($sql);
                            }
                        }catch (Exception $ex){
                            trigger_error("ERROR: ". $ex->getMessage(). "  Trace: ".$ex->getTrace());
                        }

                        $this->Session->setFlash('File imported successfully.','default',array('class'=>'sucessMsg'));

                     }
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: And your question is...what? The file is too big to be processed by that routine.

Comment: Its throws fatal error after processing few records. It says **"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in /var/domains/htdocs/aim/leads/dnc on line 1308)"**

Comment: It is exceeding the memory limit. To what ever extent i increase the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what he means is not how to extend the limits, but why the hell is this allocating 2GB of RAM?

From the looks of it, I'm assuming you're using `simplexml` to load the data. SimpleXML is a memory overkill and it can't be used for large files without exactly this happening. You should instead try using:

1. event based [SAX parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) (less memory usage than the 2nd one, but much harder to operate)
2. pull based [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php)

FYI, I've been using SAX to load about 200MB XML file with peak memory usage about 5MB, so yes, the memory consumption is uncomparable.

Comment: Yes am using cakePhp's Xml helper. AM new to XML file processing.

Comment: Ya ill try with ur suggestion but my doubt is even though am parsing the xml file by 1 record at a time. Why is that exceeding 2GB RAM

Answer (score 1):

its due to memory limit by default set in ur ini,
You can increase it via .htaccess or via ini_Set.
some additional parameters are also required as your code requires upload part too.
i have given you the method to resolve it via .htaccess.
you can also use it as ini_set by just replacing php_value with ini_set in your php page.
hope it helps you

```
php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2500M
php_value max_execution_time 6000000
php_value max_input_time 6000000
php_value memory_limit 2500M
```

Comment: Ya am already doing it.                                       php_value memory_limit 2000M
php_value post_max_size 1200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 1200M

Comment: ok,but did you tried with max_input_time too, try to increase that, try to use simplexml_load_string().

Answer (score 0):

Parsing XML with loads of data is quite a heavy task, so maybe it will be better to use regular expressions here. Try modifying your loop like this:

```
try {
    while(!feof($fp)){
        $counter = 0;
        $buffer = '';
        while(!feof($fp) && ($buffer .= fgets($fp)) && $counter++ < 1000);
        // read 1000 rows into buffer
        $matches = array();
        if (preg_match_all('/<Ph[^>]*>(\d+)</Ph>/i', $buffer, $matches) > 0) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO do_not_call_lists (`phone`) VALUES (' . implode('), (', $matches[1]) . ')';
            $this->Lead->query($sql);
        }
    }
}catch (Exception $ex){
    trigger_error("ERROR: ". $ex->getMessage(). "  Trace: ".$ex->getTrace());
}
```

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse XML a [really bad idea](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: This might be good idea. But the xml file is in the format below <list type='full' level='state' val='TX'>
<ac val='210'>
<ph val='2002033' />
<ph val='2003629' />
<ph val='2003804' />
<ph val='2005800' />
<ph val='2005801' />
<ph val='2005802' />
<ph val='2006189' />
<ph val='2006989' />
<ph val='2008401' />
<ph val='2008402' />

Comment: i need to concatenate the  <ac val='210'> with <ph val='2003629' />

Comment: @Naveen I see. Well it isn't difficult to modify this regex to catch those values. However I agree with Cypher, it isn't a right thing to do. Just one of the ways to go... Anyway I think you should first get more items into $buffer and then parse them at once rather than parsing every item separately, at least it will reduce overhead for creating parser objects.

Comment: K. Let me give a try. Thanks for the suggestion.