# Command to keep postgresql error

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp

Cakephp 1.2.6 and Postgresql 8

I run cakephp on shell.
I used save(). There are some error from Postgresql, I would like to keep that error in another database.
Who knows command in Cakephp or Postgresql that can be keep that error as string?

```
example:
if($this->Model->save($data)) { 

}
else {
/// command??
}
```

Comment: u mean `exception` that may occur when inserting int postgres DB?

Comment: try [exception -handling](http://unitstep.net/blog/2008/05/11/cakephp-and-errorexception-handling/) and 

[exceptions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html) and try this 

[showing-database-errors](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/CodingisFun/2007/06/08/showing-database-errors)

Comment: for try this also [cakephp catching error in model query](http://redhead-it.com/blog/2010/02/cakephp-catching-error-in-model-query/)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks PresleyDias

Try & Catch not work for me. Now, I used this method:

```
 $this->getDataSrouce()->error;
```

for getting last error from DB.

from : http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2011/07/05/how-to-track-sql-errors-in-cakephp-on-production-site/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to catch the `exception` and then save in the database then you can use 
somethin like this

```
   try {

         if($this->Model->save($data)){
                       //do somthing
             }

        //now the exception occured.. so catch it
       }catch (Exception $ex){

             // this message is  "ERROR: ". $ex->getMessage()
             //save the message here to the other database where the message is    $ex->getMessage() 
       }
```

from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6507084/1051198) 
also [cakephp-exception](http://www.robertchurchill.co.uk/tag/cakephp/) and [cakephp-throw-exceptions](http://www.robertchurchill.co.uk/2011/03/cakephp-throw-exceptions-with-gay-abandon/)